# What kind of version change is updating to a new .NET-version when using SemVer?

Tags: .net, versioning, semantic-versioning

When updating to a new major version of *.NET* (in this case from *.NET 5* to *.NET 6*) without needing to make any change other than selecting the new target framework in Visual Studio, does this warrant a new major or minor version or does bumping the patch version suffice, when adhering to *SemVer*-principles?

When I updated from *.NET Framework 4.8* to *.NET 5*, that was a reason to bump the major number imo, as there were a lot of changes made internally, but for the above case I'm not sure.

My app is a local executable for end users, I have no API people will have to rely on. I know it's not that important under those circumstances, but I'm still new to developing and want to learn it the "right" way from the start.

Comment: Who is _consuming_ that semantic version?

Comment: My app is for end users, I have no "real" API people will have to rely on if that's what you mean. I know it's not that important under those circumstances, but I'm new to developing and want to learn it the "right" way from the start : )

Comment: The point of semver is that consumers of your API can understand when their use of it may break and they'll need to make changes. If your consumers are end users, semver would likely apply only to the UI, not the technical implementation.

Comment: Ok, so in my case it would be minor or patch level, as the user wouldn't see anything regarding framework. But suppose I had an API, but wouldn't have to change anything about it when bumping the framework, would that still hold true?

Comment: Again, semver is about the _consumer's_ perspective. If they don't have to care that you've changed the framework (or the whole _technology_, for that matter) then it's not a major/minor version bump.

Comment: So a library's API is completely independent of the framework used and an application using that library doesn't have to care? Supposing a library is written in .NET FW 4.8 and changes to .NET 5, but changes nothing else in it's functionality, that would also only be a patch-level increment? (As I said, I'm new to all this, please excuse if I'm sounding dumb ^^")

Comment: _"a library's API is completely independent of the framework used"_ - that's certainly not true in the general case; I don't know .NET, but in other languages I've worked in changes to language and framework versions absolutely **do** mean breaking changes to libraries too. I'm saying _if_ the technology change doesn't impact consumers of your API (whether that's UI, REST, function calls, ...), then semver doesn't tell you to increment major or minor versions.

Comment: A technology change from .Net Fw 4.8 to 5.0 will definitely cause a breaking change for libraries based on that technology.

Comment: Semver is all about accurately documenting API changes. I don't think you can really practice using semver correctly if your project doesn't offer any API for other people to use.

Comment: @DocBrown I guess when you publish a library you declare what version of .net it relies on, and dependency management tools can use that info to select a compatible version for things that use the library. Certainly works that way with PHP libraries. If so there's no need to declare a major version semver change because the incompatibly is already explicit.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is related to SemVer or not, but in the case of .Net the version you have upgraded to may not be automatically available on all of the MS platforms that your users use at the time of the upgrade.  So this will affect any users who plan to upgrade (however this should be caught by your installer during installation)

Comment: @PeterM I use the framework-independent "Self-contained" mode when publishing from VS, so the user doesn't need to have the framework installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the update to the .NET Framework would affect consumers of the package or its API, I would increment the patch version number when updating dependencies.

Both the major and the minor version numbers are incremented with functional changes, with the major indicating backwards-incompatible changes and the minor indicating backwards-compatible changes. The patch version is for bug fixes, and I would argue other technical enhancements or enablements, that are backwards compatible.

The only case for updating something other than the patch version number would be if you introduced other functional changes at the same time as the dependency updates or if the dependency update could cause a breaking change for some consumers.

Partly, this depends on how your application is distributed. For example, if you are versioning an API that is consumed over HTTP, your dependencies have far less of an impact on consumers than if you are creating a library that gets included into a larger application, where upgrading technical dependencies could require consumers to install additional dependencies or invalidate existing installations upon update.

Comment: Wouldn't updating from .NET 5 -> .NET 6 on the nuget package require consumers to also be on .NET 6? Would think that since consumers need to make updates (if on .NET 5) to avoid a breaking change that would potentially be a reason to make it a major version.

Comment: @DeveloperGuy See the last paragraph. If it's a package that consumers download and include in their systems, then probably. But if it's a web API that consumers interact with over HTTP, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a change to the functionality of the code. Don't change the version number.

You can build your library to target multiple framework versions. The compiled dlls should all have the same version number, .net can tell what framework version each is for.

Comment: This contradicts one of the SemVer requirements: `Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version.` If you didn't support multiple versions and then updated the configuration to do so, the configuration file changes would trigger a version update. Also, if you need to make code changes to support a newer framework version, you would also need to update the version number. But if you are able to build against multiple frameworks with no changes to code or config, this would work.

Comment: I really mean the major and minor versions, obs new build new version. However. Having said that, adding a target would produce an additional separate output. maybe you could release that separately without changing the previously released "packages". Although the standard in .net would be a nuget with all the frameworks included in a single package, rereleasing it with extra packages.. well it would be interesting to argue

Comment: Interesting. That does open some interesting arguments or perhaps edge cases if you include the optional metadata about builds, platforms, etc. and if that satisfies the "release as a new version" requirement.